# Sculpt brush isn't drawing much detail

Tags: modeling

I already subdivided a lot from the multiresolution modifier, and when I draw with the sculpt brush it doesn't sculpt details. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You need to either enable Dynotopo or subdivide the mesh with the modifier again. Does that do what you want?

Comment: What exactly is happening? What happens when you try drawing with the brush? Do other brushes work? What do you mean by "detail"? Do you mean that it still looks like there's lots of faces like the ones visible in your screenshot, or do you mean that the geometry isn't moving much? What happens when you increase your subdivisions further with the multiresolution modifier?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the upper right corner of your window, you,ve got 29.641 vertex, it's not enough for fine details. Try subdividing until you reach 1.000.000.
In object mode switch to "Smooth Shading".
If the computer gets slow, subdivide you model in different objects (P key in edit mode mode), and sculpt them one by one, using the multiresolution modifier to swithc between different levels of details.